# Is this a valid way of using v-if and v-for in order to preserve order?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I know that `v-if` should not be used to filter elements from a list and a `computed prop` should be used instead, but what if I need to render a different thing depending on a prop from that list ?

Example: I have a list of objects, I loop through it with `v-for' and depending on a prop in that object I render one of 2 components.

```
myList: [
  {
    name: 'James',
    occupation: 'sailor'
  },
  {
    name: 'Marco',
    occupation: 'baker'
  },
]

<div v-for="(person, index) in myList" :key="index">
  <ComponentOne :name="person.name" v-if="person.occumation == sailor">
  <ComponentTwo :name="person.name" v-if="person.occumation == baker">
</div>
```

Is this a valid case since every object inside the list needs to be shown ? I know I can use computed props and 2 loops but that way I lose the order of the objects, in My scenario I need to show a different component depending on that "occupation" prop and keep them in order.

Is this A valid use of `v-if` `v-for` since I'm not using them both on the same element ?

The broader question I guess is: Is it fine to use `v-if` inside `v-for`, the guidelines only specify not using them on the same element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better way is to use [Dynamic Components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#dynamic-components-with-keep-alive). You can keep track of component with `occumation` and use it in `v-for`.

```
data() {
  return {
    myList: [
       {
         name: 'James',
         occupation: 'sailor'
       },
       {
         name: 'Marco',
         occupation: 'baker'
       }
     ],
     componentMapper: {
       sailor: 'ComponentOne',
       baker: 'ComponentTwo'
     }
  }
}

<div v-for="(person, index) in myList" :key="index">
  <component :is="componentMapper[person.occumation]" v-bind="{ name: person.name }">
</div>
```

Don't forget to register `ComponentOne && ComponentTwo` components

Comment: Yep - agreed (I was starting to right the same answer!) ... One tweak I would make is to use a computed prop for the component lookup (rather than a `componentMapper` object) - this allows you to have a default fallback, which seems like it might be useful.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for components which are offering the same interface (property bindings).

Comment: Yea, That is also good idea! Just gave him a thought so he can play with it 

Comment: @Naren Does this have any performance improvements or anything like that too ? It certainly much cleaner than what I'm currently doing with `v-ifs`, say no so I won't feel the need to refactor everything :)

Comment: If you have many components with the same interface and you would use many `v-if`s, use this approach. Otherwise, go with a simple `v-if`.

Comment: If you want switch between the components, for example tabs, let's say, you don't want re-render the component every time time you change the tab(think if the tab has heavy computations). In such cases you can use `dynamic components` with `is` and `keep-alive`. This can of course  improve the performance. Read the link that mention in the answer, you'll understand more how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is fine to use `v-if` inside `v-for`. It should only not be used on the same element as `v-for` because the order of execution might be misleading in that case (`v-for` is executed before `v-if`). See also the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for).

Comment: This answer doesn't really approach the specific question being asked. See @Naren's answer for more complete info.

Comment: @BenHull Yes it does answer the question. The other answer just proposes an alternative approach. Usually that approach is just not necessary and a simple `v-if` is more than enough. The added complexity it brings is just not worth it (except in some cases where you have a lot of different components with always the same property interface).